# I'm getting this error "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Tags: cors, fetch

I have disabled all CORS settings on destination server but still get this error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

But when I did `--disable-web-security` in browser, then the error is gone... why?

I'm trying to get multiple cross-domain requests

Answer (score -1):

The error you're seeing is related to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). When a web page makes an AJAX request to a different domain, the browser performs a "preflight" request (an HTTP OPTIONS request) to check if the actual request is allowed from the domain it's being made from.

1. CORS Headers on Destination Server: Even if you've disabled CORS headers on the destination server, the browser will still enforce CORS policies based on the headers it receives.

2.Why the Error is Gone with Web Security Disabled: With web security disabled, the browser doesn't enforce CORS restrictions, so the request is allowed. Essentially, you've bypassed the security measure that's in place to prevent certain types of malicious actions.

Hope you are able to understand...

Comment: Thanks Akshat sir, If you have any link then please share with us, so we can make changes accordingly..to avoid the same error.